# Can't get full CA chain using libcurl

Tags: curl, openssl, libcurl, ca

I want to get api.dropboxapi.com's Root CA to pass SSL check
But i can only get 2 certs using libcurl, which the domain has 3 certs.
Here is my Code, use libcurl CURLOPT_CERTINFO, Test on WSL2 Debian

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t wrfu(void *ptr,  size_t  size,  size_t  nmemb,  void *stream)
{
  (void)stream;
  (void)ptr;
  return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wrfu);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(!res) {
      struct curl_certinfo *certinfo;

      res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CERTINFO, &certinfo);

      if(!res && certinfo) {
        int i;

        printf("%d certs!\n", certinfo->num_of_certs);

        for(i = 0; i < certinfo->num_of_certs; i++) {
          struct curl_slist *slist;

          for(slist = certinfo->certinfo[i]; slist; slist = slist->next)
            printf("%s\n", slist->data);

        }
      }

    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

From the output, i find the Root CA missing, but other domain, like youtube.com、google.com can get a full ca chain. I test somemore Websites which use DigiCert signed CA, it all have same problem.

Did these websites have more steps to get ca chain?

Comment: Servers can but not mandatory send root certificates. Root certificates should be found in the system trusted certificate storage.

Comment: As @273K says. curl returns all the certificates the server provides. No more, no less.